# import JSON in R to create a dataframe

Tags: json, r, dataframe

Hello I have the following JSON file with 3 observation (each observation called SINGLE) and the last observation is just the SUM.

I would like how to import all the "SINGLE" observation in R:

I've tried the following code:

```
library("rjson")
json_file <- "my_file.json"
json_data <- fromJSON(file=json_file)
```

But my issue is that next I do now know how to format my data.

If I perform this code it won't work

```
data= as.data.frame(json_data$SINGLE)
```

I would like to get the "TS" as row and the other variable (page post , user post, etc.) as column.

So I belive I need to find a kind of loop to create the data.frame but I do not know how to do. Someone can help me?

JSON sample:

```
{"SINGLE":[{"TS":1422777600,"page_posts":8,"user_posts":9,"UM":0,"PT":39,"ST":29,"RE":477,"page_impressions":1703,"clicks":68,"new_likes":10,"virality_pimp_unique":96,"virality_pimp_viral_unique":392,"post_likes":6,"post_shares":0,"post_comments":0},{"TS":1422864000,"page_posts":7,"user_posts":7,"UM":0,"PT":45,"ST":37,"RE":405,"page_impressions":2305,"clicks":52,"new_likes":19,"virality_pimp_unique":127,"virality_pimp_viral_unique":294,"post_likes":6,"post_shares":0,"post_comments":0},{"TS":1424851200,"page_posts":8,"user_posts":16,"UM":0,"PT":135,"ST":51,"RE":1049,"page_impressions":8919,"clicks":200,"new_likes":2,"virality_pimp_unique":729,"virality_pimp_viral_unique":339,"post_likes":23,"post_shares":0,"post_comments":1}],"SUM":{"page_posts":196,"user_posts":232,"UM":5,"PT":3018,"ST":2325,"RE":19112,"page_impressions":117514,"clicks":3714,"new_likes":1124,"virality_pimp_unique":10176,"virality_pimp_viral_unique":9622,"post_likes":710,"post_shares":2,"post_comments":36,"lifetime_likes":2741}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `jsonlite` package does this automatically:

```
library(jsonlite)
mydata <- fromJSON("my_file.json")$SINGLE
row.names(mydata) <- mydata$TS
```

Comment: Dear Jeroen, thanks a lot I ignored the existance of jsonlite